# Slideshow mode: how to cycle slides automatically?

Tags: slideshows

I'm doing a slideshow for an informative conference, so I need a slideshow running in background on some monitors.

My question is: is there any way to make *Mathematica* to cycle slides automatically?
[`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html), [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html) and [`SlideView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlideView.html) have the "Play" button by which one can set the speed. I'd need something similar for the slideshow.

Any idea is welcome, also those which require the editing of notebook code.

Comment: Related: [17394](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/dashboard-tv-with-cdf-player)

Answer (score 7):

When I execute this code at the beginning of a slideshow, the cells are presented one after the other and the slides change automatically.

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[]; n = 20; 
While[True, SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook]; 
  Do[SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]; SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell]; 
  Pause[1], {n}]]
```

You might want to change `n`, and either hide the evaluating cell manually or with code.

You do not have to put that code in your slide show. In fact, you can open the slide show with code from another notebook. In that case, you should change the first command to something like

```
nb = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[docpath, "document.nb"]];
```

Comment: Thank: it seems to work! Do you thin isn't there a method to perform it without the "selection move"?

Comment: You might want to set an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macro that sends `PageDown` and `Ctrl`+`Home` keystrokes to Mathematica.

Comment: @Hector, that's Windows only.